# Unable to reinstall packages with new version of R

Tags: r, package, compatibility

I have had issues with testing an old R app locally (causes R to crash, fatal error), and as a first de-bugging step I'm trying to update the installed packages to my version of R, which is much newer than the versions used in creating the app. However, I get an error that the library is not writable when I try to update the packages - I'm not super familiar with R so any help here is appreciated! Thank you

`sessionInfo()`

> R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
> Running under: macOS Monterey 12.6.6

I got the following error when I tried running
 `update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)`:

> Warning in install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l, repos = repos,  :
> 'lib = "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library"' is not writable
> Would you like to use a personal library instead? (yes/No/cancel)

Comment: You can to type "yes" and press enter. But note that this library will not have your old packages. You need to reinstall those using `install.packages()`.

Comment: This is a permissions issue. It is NOT pan issue of compatibility of the package with your still considerably out of date version of R.